# What is the difference between PPE and SPPE?

Tags: security-definition, pseudo-random-permutation

Can somebody explain, in simple terms, the difference between Pseudo Random Permutation Ensemble and Super Pseudo Random Permutation Ensemble?

Comment: “Super Pseudo-Random Permutations” are simply **Strong** Pseudo-Random Permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Super-Pseudo-Random**

A function family is super-pseudo-random if no polynomial time adversary can tell the difference between a function from the family and a real random function, given oracle access to the function and its inverse. (As a practical example: block ciphers are typically modeled as super-pseudo-random permutations.)

So, defining it a bit: a family of permutations $f_k(x)$ (where $|k|=n$ and $|x|=m$) is super-pseudo-random if for every polynomial time oracle algorithm A, the difference between the probability that A outputs one in the following two experiments is negligible:

- Choose $k$ at random, and run A with oracle access to $f_k$ and $(f_k)^{-1}$.
- Choose $f$ as a random permutation from $\{0,1\}^m$ to $\{0,1\}^m$, and run $A$ with oracle access to $f$ and $f^{-1}$. (Technically, $f$ is implemented as an algorithm that keeps track of all the queries asked by $A$, and answers new queries at random)

It is also assumed that $f_k$ and its inverse can be efficiently computed, given knowledge of the key $k$.

The above permutations are called super-pseudo-random because $A$ is given access to both $f$ and its inverse, so $A$ can make both encryption and decryption queries to the block cipher.

**Pseudo-Random**

A similar definition where $A$ has only access to $f$ results in the standard definition of pseudo-random permutation. (Note: super-pseudo-random permutations can be efficiently obtained from pseudo-random functions, using a construction of Luby-Rackoff… but that's another story.)

Comment: I think "of pseudo-random function" should be replaced with "of pseudo-random permutations", $\hspace{.6 in}$ since those can be easily distinguished from each other when the domain is small. $\:$ I also think you should put back-slashes before each of the brackets around $0,1$ in your LaTeX. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Valid point [+1], and thanks for the heads-up on those brackets too.

Comment: @e-sushi can u give me pointer to luby-rackoff construction of SPRP you are talking about ?

Comment: [M. Luby, C. Rackoff, "How to construct pseudorandom permutations from pseudorandom functions", SIAM Journal on Computing, 17 (2) (1988), pp. 373–386](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-39799-X_34). Thinking about it, you might also want to check on ["A construction of the simplest super pseudorandom permutation generator" by Lee, Kim, and Choi](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089812219500026U) and ["Building PRFs from PRPs" by Hall, Wagner, Kelsey, and Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/paper-prf-prp.pdf)‎ (which build upon and mention that Luby-Rackoff paper).

Comment: @sashank There are a few more related papers out there which might be interesting — depending on how deep you want to dive into the *"super"* version — but the two I mentioned (besides the Luby-Rackoff paper itself) should be able to provide a nice start.

Comment: yeah am aware of those references except Lee,Kim's one . am actually looking for Super PRP from PRF Constructions u mentioned of

Comment: @sashank Then check the original Luby-Rachoff paper. (Didn't find a *free* PDF link to provide to you; but http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0217022 and http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-39799-X_34 and some others offer it.)

Answer (score 3):

An efficiently computable Permutation Ensemble is (Weakly) Pseudo-Random

if and only if it is infeasible for an adversary with oracle access to

[a function that was chosen either from then Ensemble or uniformly from

the set of all permutations on bit-strings of the corresponding length]

to distinguish between those two cases.

An efficiently computable Permutation Ensemble is "Super" (= Strongly) Pseudo-Random

if and only if it is infeasible for an adversary with oracle access to

[$\hspace{.02 in}$[a function that was chosen either from then Ensemble or uniformly from

the set of all permutations on bit-strings of the corresponding length] *and* that function's inverse]

to distinguish between those two cases.